# How to add a value in the cells of a specific column in a datagridview in c#.net?

Tags: c#, datagridview

This is what my datagridview looks like:

[image]

The values Name, Price, Total, and Quantity column is loaded from a database. I want to add an initial value zero(0) to the "Item/s Added or Subtracted" column.

This is how I populate my datagridview:

```
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Stock");
cm.Connection = con;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
da.Fill(dt);
stockGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
stockGridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Name";
stockGridView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Price";
stockGridView.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Total";
stockGridView.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
stockGridView.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

My + and - column are now working and can now increment/decrement by 1, and the incremented/decremented value can be displayed in the "Item/s Added or Subtracted" column, but it will be better if I can put an initial value there.

I have tried this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn("addOrSubtractItem", typeof(String));
newColumn.DefaultValue = 0;
dt.Columns.Add(newColumn);
```

but it doesn't display the 0

I also tried: reference -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/unbound-column-to-a-data-bound-datagridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn buttonColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
buttonColumn.Name = "Item/s Added or Subtracted";
buttonColumn.HeaderText = "Item/s Added or Subtracted";
stockGridView.Columns.Insert(4, buttonColumn);
```

but I cant put the 0 value in the cells.

Comment: The defaultvalue will be used when adding new rows to the datatable. So i assume you haven't added the rows shown via Add/Create but filled it into the datatable via some other means like a query from a Tableadapter. You need to set the value for the row explictly at all DataRow object in the DataTable.

Comment: I manually add the column using the "Edit Columns" in the datagridview, and I tried to put a value in "Item/s Added or Subtracted" column.

Comment: Use `typeof(int)` instead of `typeof(string)`

Comment: I have to ask… What is the purpose of the “Item/s Added or Subtracted” column? Is it adding or subtracting a “Quantity” value? I am just curious “how” this column is used in relation to the other columns in the table, considering the column is NOT in the DB, then, “how” would you “save” this value? Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnG it is just for visual purposes, so the user will know how many items did he add/subtract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it basically well, but not completely. After fill datatable from DB you add new column to datatable and set all rows to "0" value. Then you set DataTable as datasource of GridView.

Program code example:

```
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Stock");
cm.Connection = con;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();

//add new column to Datatable
dt.Columns.Add("addOrSubtractItem", typeof(int));
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    dr["addOrSubtractItem"] = 0;
}

stockGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
stockGridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Name";
stockGridView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Price";
stockGridView.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Total";
stockGridView.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
stockGridView.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "addOrSubtractItem";
stockGridView.DataSource = dt;
```